# How to get a node by its url alias?

Tags: 7, nodes

I know I can load a node by its title with the `node_load()` function. Is it possible to load a node by its URL alias?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You want to investigate [menu_get_object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) and [drupal_lookup_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/7).

Something like this would do what you want:

```
$alias = "some/path/to/a/page";
$path = drupal_lookup_path("source", $alias);
$node = menu_get_object("node", 1, $path);
```

Comment: Also, to dynamically grab url alias do next:
$alias = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$alias = substr($alias, 1); // to remove "/" from beginning of string

Comment: @EugenePavlov - `$alias = drupal_get_path_alias();` should be it.

Answer (score 2):

For somebody looking to find how to do this in Drupal 8 here is the corresponding question and answer

[How can I get the node ID from a path alias?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197157/how-can-i-get-the-nid-of-a-node-from-the-page-alias)

```
use \Drupal\Core\Url;

$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias('/etapes-de-la-vie');
$params = Url::fromUri("internal:" . $alias)->getRouteParameters();
$entity_type = key($params);
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($params[$entity_type]);
```

For **Drupal 9** use `\Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')` instead of `\Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')`