# How can I convert a node title to a lowercase string with hyphens?

Tags: 7

I need to convert the title of a node, for example, from this

> John Doe

to

> john-doe

Is there Drupal function for it? (Easier to use than using preg_preplace etc.)

Comment: Hi, glad you got an answer but what you're asking has nothing to do with Drupal, and I think keeping this open is going to confuse people as it's entirely a PHP issue. I removed the confusing terminology about "human readable node names" etc, and changed the question only to contain what you're really asking

Comment: I don't fully agree with "off-topic". There is `drupal_html_class($class)` function in core.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic either.

    module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto', 'pathauto');
    $hyphened = pathauto_cleanstring('John Doe');

Comment: not off-topic, Drupal has functions to achieve a lot of things that PHP sucks at.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're just looking for a way to convert the title into a URL friendly machine name, then the following regex will do what you need:

```
$machine_name = preg_replace('@[^a-z0-9-]+@','-', strtolower($title));
```

Comment: Thank you @littledynamo This is exactly what I needed. Also thank you for making my question clearer.

Comment: @BoutrosAbiChedid Bear in mind this method will not mimic your pathauto settings - if you change those, to exclude/include a certain character, for example, this method will not keep up-to-date. It's much better to use the API methods (if you're not using Pathauto just ignore this)

Comment: @littledynamo I am not using Pathauto so your method is great. Thanks.

Comment: You can also user $name = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower('John Doe'));

Comment: Yeah that will work and is more performant (provided the title doesn't contain any slashes or such like).

Answer (score 0):

[Check this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/15247/9032).

If you are on the node template (ie. *node.tpl.php*), you should have `$node->nid` available.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question? $node->nid returns a number, not at all what the OP asked.