# Load and render all pages from main menu

Tags: nodes, routes, theming

I'm trying to create a one-pager website in which I'd like to get all the main-menu links and load their complete content underneath each other on the homepage. So that's blocks, display etc. in all.

So I was thinking I could just get the page and render it in an each link; but I can't figure out how I can load and render multiple pages in one go.

I make a preprocess_page hook and got the menu links I want. How do I go about and get all those pages underneath each other now?

```
function myproject_preprocess_page (&$vars) {

    //Get ALL The pages from the main menu and ALL the content
    //And make one large content for all of it to create a one-pager
    if (isset($vars['node']) && strtolower($vars['node']->title) == "home") {
        $menu = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
        if ($menu) {
            foreach ($menu as $menuItem) {
                $a = menu_get_item($menuItem['mlid']);
                //echo render ($a); // Gives nothing
                //echo drupal_render_page($a); //time-out
            }

        }


}
```

}

I also tried with menu_load_links but I can't really see if I'm extracting the node now and how to render that.

```
$menu = menu_load_links('main-menu');

if ($menu) {
    foreach ($menu as $item) {
        $b = menu_get_item($item['link_path']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot render menu entries, but render arrays. you need to get the node from the menu item's path ([see here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15245/how-to-get-a-node-by-its-url-alias)) and then you can use [node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7) to get its render array.

a way better solution would be to make a views page, with a [menu_node](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_node) relationship.