# How can I get the node ID from a path alias?

Tags: 8, nodes, path-aliases

I want to be able to get the nid but the only information I have is http://example.com/this-is-the-alias.

Is there a way to get either the internal path of /node/*  for that alias if I am not on the page?  Or is there a way to just get the nid from that alias right away?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a direct function, but one route is to use the path alias manager service to lookup the internal path then regex it for a valid node id to perform an object load on:

```php
$path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias('/this-is-the-alias');

if (preg_match('/node\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches)) {
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($matches[1]);
}
```

### Drupal 9

In Drupal 9 the service has been renamed.

```php
$path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getPathByAlias('/this-is-the-alias');
```

Comment: For some reason, `$path` is sometimes equal to `/this-is-the-alias`. Once was when the root path (`node/{id}`) was another alias #migrationstruggles, but it was also present with other aliases.

Comment: Please remember, if you are using Drupal 8 with translated pages, you need to inform the language in the second parameter:
$path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias('/this-is-the-alias', $langcode);

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following code to get and load an entity and have access to its values.

```
  use \Drupal\Core\Url;

  $alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias('/etapes-de-la-vie');

  $params = Url::fromUri("internal:" . $alias)->getRouteParameters();
  $entity_type = key($params);
  $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($params[$entity_type]);
  //to use dpm you need the devel module
  dpm($node->nid->value);
```

#### References

- [Drupal 8: get entity object given system path?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2309797#comment-11738958)

Comment: You don't need to resolve the alias, just feed the relative URL into the `Url::fromUserInput` and then call the `getRouteParameters`

Answer (score 3):

Install the devel module and then use the devel toolbar item *Current route info*.

This results in this url, which you can type in directly and provide any path known to your drupal installation as query parameter:

```
/devel/routes/item?path=alias
```

When it is a node you find the node id in the raw parameters at the end of the listed route variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, so you avoid direct regexs.

```
$parsed_url = UrlHelper::parse($alias);
$path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getPathByAlias($parsed_url['path']);
$params = Url::fromUserInput($path)->getRouteParameters();
$entity_type_id = array_key_first($params);
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type_id)->load($params[$entity_type_id]);
```