# Get node internal path from path alias in Twig template

Tags: 8, theming, path-aliases

I want to get the internal path of a node from its path alias. In Drupal 7 we could use `drupal_get_normal_path()` directly in the PHP template.

With Drupal 8, Is there a function to get the internal path from an alias inside a Twig template?

In my Twig template I have tried to use the `url()` function without success...

e.g. `{% set path = url('myalias') %}` ...

Comment: I haven't the node id. I want get the internal path (node/nid) from the alias. I need to get the nid of a node from the alias.

Comment: Ah now I got it! Better do this in a preprocess function and then pass it over to Twig. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/197163/15055

Comment: Which template are you currently using?

Comment: Ok there is no possibility to use directly a drupal function in my twig template ? I need to generate several nids inside a views table template. I will see to create a custom function to pass an alias and get the related nid. Create a var in a preprocess function isn't very usefull for my case.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. If you have a view that displays nodes in a table then I would expect that the nid is definitely somewhere that is available to you. Might help if you add the your current template and what exactly you are trying to do with that path/nid. There is certainly a better way to get the nid than unaliasing the alias (which actually needs to a DB query)

Comment: are you after the path or just the nid?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be running Drupal functions inside TWIG templates, the best approach is to use a pre-processor as mentioned in the comments. You can do this by setting a variable inside a hook being called either in your theme file or custom module and setting like this:

```
$vars['your_custom_variable'] = $unaliasedNodePath
```

And then inside your twig template you can use the variable set in your pre-processor like this:

```
{{ your_custom_variable }}
```

More information can be found here:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-best-practices-preprocess-functions-and-templates