# How can I override a displayed node with the content rendered by a custom module?

Tags: routes, 9

I have a path /application, which is rendered by a custom module (through a combination of theme hook/controller/routing/twig). It's basically a mini-application.

I also have a Drupal node /data, which is a Drupal node with content loaded by Drupal.

However, I need to load the contents of /application at /data. I tried setting the routing of my custom module to use /data instead of /application, but Drupal still loads the Drupal node content at /data rather than the custom module content. The catch is, this particular application uses fields from that node, so I don't want to delete the node. I just want to change what gets rendered when you view the node, but leave it active and editable.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: In order to load variables before the node is rendered, you need to use HOOK_preprocess_node, did you try that?

Comment: Change the node’s path to something that isn’t /data. Problem solved.

Comment: @Clive Ideally I'm not changing the node path because I want to retain where the node is used in menus. Is there no way to override the view of a node with a custom module?

Comment: @HodbaKhalaf I tried that but can't see a way to load everything from a custom module into the node viewer. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Drupal first uses the path aliases, then the routes defined from modules. If you were to add a node with /admin/config/people/accounts as path alias, you won't see anymore the settings page for the accounts.

Comment: @Anton in the preprocessor you can unset the content and set your values generated in the custom module e.g. $variables['VARIABLE_NAME'] then you can theme it with the twig file. if you can share some code, maybe I can give you better feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since /data is a path alias for a node, Drupal shows that node instead of showing what a controller associated to that path returns. If you were to set a node path alias to /admin/config/people/accounts, Drupal would show that node instead of the accounts setting page.

If you want to change the render array used for a node, you need to implement [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/9.3.x). You can compare `$entity->id()` with the node ID to which you want add data in its render array.

```php
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($entity->id() == 3) {
    // Change $build.
  }
}
```

You can also find the node ID given its path alias, for example with code similar to the following one.

```php
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  $path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getPathByAlias('/data');

  if (preg_match('/node\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches)) {
    if ($entity->id() == $matches[1]) {
      // Change $build.
    }
  }
}
```

See [How can I get the node ID from a path alias?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197157/how-can-i-get-the-node-id-from-a-path-alias) which also explains when to use the *path_alias.manager* or the *path.alias_manager* service.

(As a side note, if I were to use this code in sites where the content is exported from a site and imported in those sites, I would compare the node UUID with the value I expect for the node I need to handle. This works only when the node UUIDs are kept when importing content.)

Comment: Great idea! I was able to load my custom module content instead here by adding to $build. One question I have for this is: inside hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view(), instead of using the $entity->id(), is there any elegant way to use the custom module's routing.yml to get and call the appropriate controller method dynamically? Otherwise I'm hard-coding ids which feels the same as just creating a 'node--3.html.twig' type of override, and also hard-coding what controller and method to load content from.

Comment: You can get the node ID given the path alias, as I show in the updated answer. The code is still hard-coding a value (the path alias), but it's easier to set the same path alias on different sites than getting the same node ID for nodes on different sites.