# How to load page content by url programmatically in custom region

Tags: theming, uri

How to load page content **/node/add/page**  programmatically in custom region? Example of custom region (https://jsfiddle.net/makbuk/1vetkgL2/).

I have found this [How to get a node by its url alias?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15245/how-to-get-a-node-by-its-url-alias) but it dosn't work for me.

```
$alias = "some/path/to/a/page";
$path = drupal_lookup_path("source", $alias);
$node = menu_get_object("node", 1, $path);
```

Comment: Are you trying to load the node form, or the node content? Also I assume this is for Drupal 7, but saying which version you're using is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or
>   **node creation forms in blocks**. This is particularly useful for including forms on panels.

Then in blocks (`/admin/structure/block`), assign the Form Block to your desired region.

Comment: It works for me, it came without programming, thanks.