# How to load page content by url programmatically

Tags: uri, path-aliases

My custom module needs content of a page generated by another custom module. Please note I am not trying to pull a node content, so my question is different than one on [How to load page content by url programmatically in custom region](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207598/how-to-load-page-content-by-url-programmatically-in-custom-region)

If I put `dpm(render($page['content']));` in page.tpl.php and go to the page generated by the other module then it outputs the exact part that my module needs. Unfortunately, the other module doesn't provide a hook for the needed content part, so I need to first load that page and then extract $page['content'] part.

Is there any way to load a custom Drupal page's content knowing only its URL?

Comment: Can you say please why your module needs content of another page? I think we may help you to do it in another scenario.

Comment: Does it really matter why? But if you really think it helps then here is why. We are trying to put the output of another custom Drupal module into http://www.jqueryscript.net/accordion/Easy-Responsive-Tab-Accordion-Control-Plugin-For-jQuery.html

Comment: If you are mean you want render nodes into this accordion? You can achieve this by create view and use (views_accordion Module). Or even you can create a custom block in your custom module and show the result as you want inside this block. It's not recommended to load Drupal pages inside one page this will be performance issue. So that's why I ask you to tell us why you need this case to help you done the final result in a better way.

Comment: Saud, why loose your time when you can clearly read in the description: "Please note I am not trying to pull a node content." And forget about your concerns, just answer the question if you have any valuable input, and pass by if you don't!

Comment: Sorry Nick, Good luck.